# C compile error Variable-sized object may not be initialized with char * ptr[buflen]

Tags: c, compiler-errors, initializer-list, variable-length-array

Yes I did read these two posts.

[C compile error: "Variable-sized object may not be initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082914/c-compile-error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized)
[C error "variable-sized object may not be initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186879/c-error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized)

My case is a bit different because I'm using `char * ptr[buflen]`. This is what I have tried:

```
char  *ptr[buflen] = {0};  //This gave me the variable sized object error. 

char  *ptr[buflen];
memset( ptr, 0, buflen*buflen*sizeof(char)); //I figured this would work with looking at the previous examples. 

//This seemed to work but I am curious if I need to use free or malloc
after looking at the previous examples. I don't want this to seg fault later
in the program and have no clue what is causing it. 
char  *ptr[buflen]; 
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof ptr);

char *strings_line_tokens[503] = {0}; //Why does this work but the above won't work?
```

Comment: `memset(ptr, 0, buflen*sizeof(char *))`. Though *technically* a NULL-ptr doesn't have to be zero, so you should *probably*  just use a loop to initialize all pointers.

Comment: `char  *ptr[buflen] = {0}` should be `char  *ptr[buflen] = {NULL}`

Comment: What are you going to store in `ptr` I think you are confused about that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Why the bikeshedding? It's the same thing in this context.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I"ve seen compilers complain if you try an initialize an array of pointers to `0` instead of `NULL`. Which compiler would help.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Sounds like you've used a broken compiler.

Comment: Yes but you can't initialize a variable length array anyway!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, a real C compiler should never complain about that. A C++ would probably, but C is different.

Comment: @iharob has the primary concern, I think that is probably the main issue.

Comment: @rocker, why is your case different from the one that you have in the link? How does the answer that is given there not give you enough information to figure things out?

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't know if I need to use free or malloc. They both could be important with what I'm doing. I missed the `*` at the end of  `memset(ptr, 0, buflen*sizeof(char *))`.

Comment: For the arrays themselves as you define them you wouldn't need dynamic allocation through `malloc`, this is the whole idea of variable length arrays. But then you have arrays of pointers, but didn't tell us what you want to do with them, so we can't know.

Comment: @iharob `ptr` will contain an array of strings. I needed to check if it contained a new line character or null character. When I tried do that it segfaulted because it hadn't been initialized. So I tried to initialize this. And that is why I would like to know if I need malloc or free.

Comment: No it will contain an array of pointers, if the pointers point to strings that's another thing.

Comment: @iharob I fill it with strings.

Answer (score 0):

> My case is a bit different because I'm using char * ptr[buflen].

Not really.  You're declaring `ptr` as a `buflen`-sized array of `char *`.  If `buflen` is not a *constant expression*, then `ptr` is a variable-length array, and you may not use an initializer for a variable-length array:

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> ...
> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
> object type **that is not a variable length array type**.

Emphasis added.

So, quite simply,

```
char *ptr[buflen] = {0};
```

is not a legal initialization.

If you want to initialize all the elements of `ptr` to `0` or `NULL`, you would use `memset`:

```
memset( ptr, 0, sizeof *ptr * buflen ); // note memset writes 0 to all *bytes* in 
                                        // in the array
```

or you would assign each element in a loop:

```
for ( size_t i; i < buflen; i++ )
  ptr[i] = NULL; // or 0, or some other pointer value
```

Comment: So this didn't do what I expected `memset(ptr, 0, sizeof ptr);`? It didn't  give me any compiler warning and didn't segfault.

Comment: @rocker: bugger.  Let me fix that.

Comment: @rocker: my fault - that line should be `memset( ptr, 0, sizeof *ptr * buflen);`.  I've been working with pointers to arrays vs. arrays of pointers lately and got my wires crossed.