# Error with array[players] = {0.0

Tags: arrays

I am trying to program a game. In this game the user is supposed to enter the number of players and the amount of fields this game has. I tried to use an array to keep track of the score of all players. Therefore I did `int score[abplayers]`, so there are different scores for every player. The problem is that when I try to define all scores to 0. I tried with 0.0, but I get

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please post more relevant code and the full compiler output.

Comment: Identifying the language would help, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082914/c-compile-error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized

Comment: By the way, trying 0.0 (a float or double) is not a good idea because the chosen data type is int.  You had the 0 right the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abplayers is a variable, so score is a variable sized array.  The compiler won't know how much memory it takes, so refuses to initialize it that way.

You can make it a fixed size array, or you can keep it variable, but define a function to assign values, certain to check that no assignment goes past the bounds, abplayer.

Comment: So how exactly do I do that. Do I create a condition which invalidates the use of higher numbers or do I create a loop

Comment: Where do the initial values come from?

Answer (score 0):

First, your score type is int so you cannot assign '0.0', you have to asign '0'.

To initialize an array you have to create the array. As the compiler does not know the value of *abplayers* it does not know the size of the array *score* and cannot create the array.

The solution is to initialize all the scores to '0' once the users enters the number of players.