# why can C++ "fill" initialize a variable-sized array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, clang++, variable-length-array

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void aa(int n) {
    int test[n] = {0};
}
int main() {
    aa(10);
    return 0;
}
```

and got

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

but

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void aa(int n) {
    int test[n];
    fill(test,test+10,0);
}
int main() {
    aa(10);
    return 0;
}
```

is ok

I want to know the reason why this one got compiled while the former failed.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using?

Comment: Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2) @Evg

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/SkNQ2eKhB first code also working

Comment: Neither is legal since n is not compile time constant

Comment: You might want to use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VLA are not part of C++. They are supported by some compilers as an extension. They come from C99, and in C99 [you cannot initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082914/c-compile-error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized) VLA with `= {0};`. Some compilers (like GCC) go further and add support for such an initialization. In GCC this syntax can be used starting from [version 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html#cxx). Clang apparently doesn't support it, and it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array only with constant size, which can be deduced at compile time. variable `n` can be known only at runtime.

To elaborate, when you allocate memory on the stack, the size must be known at compile time. Since the arrays are local to the method, they will be placed on the stack.

Comment: actually I'm curious why can't I allocate a variable-sized array on stack at runtime

Comment: The first line of my comment answers your question

Comment: @jinzhenhui, this is an unfortunate limitation of C++ at the time. There are [proposals](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3662.html) to fix it.

Comment: thank you very much @Evg that's exactly the answer I want

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your examples is legal since `n` is not compile time constant and standard C++ doesn't allow non-const length for array initialisation (C does however).

The reason why your second example compiles is, that you address the seemingly only problem your compiler has with your first example, i.e. it is not initialized.

[I recommend compiling with all compiler warnings enabled, which probably should be default anyway.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings/57842757#57842757) You can enable them in GCC for example with `-Wall -Wextra` and optionally `-Werror`. If you want your compiler to strictly stick to the standard, add `-pedantic`, too.

You might want to use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) instead. If that is the case, your code would become

```cpp
#include <vector>

void aa(int n) {
    // 1st parameter: number of elements, 2nd: value of elements.
    std::vector<int> test(n, 0); 
    // test.resize(n, 0); // is also possible
    // std::fill(test.begin(), test.end(), 0); // is also possible
}

int main() {
    aa(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enabling warnings will not do anything for the second example. You need the `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` flag for Clang and GCC to give a diagnostic for the use of VLAs.

Comment: thanks, actually I'm just wondering is there any reason that makes allocating a variable-sized array on stack at runtime impossible.

Comment: @jinzhenhui https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887178/4850111 answers why VLAs aren't standard C++