# Unexpected characters at the start of char array

Tags: c, string, character-encoding

i have been trying to write the order in which the tree is traversed, to a .txt file in C. Instead of using arrays, i'm using my own data type *vector* to store the node values of the tree. I then try to create a character array from the items in the vector. This  process goes as expected, however when i print the char array to the screen, it prints 5 random character in the beginning. I'm sure enough that the problem isn't in the *vector* but elsewhere because when i try to print the characters inside the loop, it doesn't print any unexpected characters to the screen (please see image below). Help in spotting the bug will be highly appreciated.

```
NODE* char_tree = optimised_tree(); // First Node of the tree
vector* tree_items = new_vector();
parse_tree(char_tree, tree_items); // parses the tree and add nodes to vector

int len = vec_size(tree_items); // size of the vector
char xs[len + 2];
char x[2];

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    int o = vec_get(tree_items, i); // item at index i in vector tree_items
    printf("%c ", o);
    x[0] = (char)o;
    x[1] = '\0';
    strcat(xs, x);
}

xs[len] = '\n';
xs[len + 1] = '\0';
printf("\n-> %sSIZE %lu\n", xs, sizeof(xs));
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the variable `xs` without initializing it! The code:

```c
char xs[len + 2];
```

**declares** a character array but does not assign anything to it. So, you have a character array with arbitrary (= 'random') content.

To solve your problem, just initialize `xs` to an empty string, either when you declare it (see note below), or (better, IMHO) with code like the following before the start of the `for` loop:

```c
strcpy(xs, "");
```

Note: You *cannot* use normal [initializer syntax on variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3082914/10871073)! So, code like this will not work:

```c
char xs[len + 2] = ""; // Cannot initialize VLA
```

but you *could* do this:

```c
char xs[len + 2]; xs[0] = 0;
```

Comment: @Syed.bcc: A more obvious `xs[i] = o;` instead of creating then concatenating a temporary string should have circumvented your problem as well. Then you don't have to initialize the string to an empty one first.

Comment: @AdrianMole: OP named the variable that picks up the character code `o` ("oh"). There is no need for a `0` (zero) inside the loop.

Comment: @usr2564301 OK! I misunderstood - now I get your idea (keeps things simple).

Comment: @Syed.bcc See edit (and the linked Q/A) on why you cannot use initializer syntax on your VLA.

Comment: @AdrianMole it seems like i should be using memset instead direct assignment.

Comment: @AdrianMole just noticed the edit. thanks for making it clear.

Comment: @Syed.bcc: do not downvote random questions or answers "in revenge". If I considered my approach superior to AdrianMole's (working) answer I would have posted it as such.