# c initialize array and structs at the same time

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialize both an array and the structs that it contains

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct
{
    int  rgbtBlue;
    int  rgbtGreen;
    int  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;

void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]);

int main()
{
    int height = 3;
    int width = 3;
    RGBTRIPLE image[height][width] = {
        {{0, 10, 25}, {0, 10, 30}, {40, 60, 80}},
        {{20, 30, 90}, {30, 40, 100}, {80, 70, 90}},
        {{20, 20, 40}, {30, 10, 30}, {50, 40, 10}}
    };
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure whether this initialization can happen at the same time or if I must initialize first all the structs before inserting them into the array.

Comment: Do you get an error when you compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give initial values for the elements in an array, including members of structures in the array, when defining an array.

The C standard says a thing being initialized shall not have variable length array type (C 2018 6.7.9 3). Your array has variable length array type because `height` and `width` are variables, not constants as C defines them. To fix that, you can use `#define` directives or `enum` declarations to define `height` and `width`.

If you do need a variable length array or a dynamically allocated array, you can give values to its elements using assignment statements, including assignments of whole structures using a *compound literal* for each structure, as in:

```
image[i][j] = (RGBTRIPLE) { 0, 10, 25 };
```

However, the C standard does not provide any way to give initial values to a variable length array or dynamically allocated array during its creation. With optimization, assigning values immediately after creating an array will likely be equivalent to initializing them during creation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is not due to the fact that you have an array of structures; rather, it is because it is a variable length array (VLA), and [VLAs cannot be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3082914/10871073).

To fix this (assuming you are using a GCC-compatible compiler, as hinted by your use of `__attribute__((__packed__))`), you can declare the `height` and `width` 'variables' as `const`:

```c
int main()
{
    const int height = 3;
    const int width = 3;
    RGBTRIPLE image[height][width] = {
        {{0, 10, 25}, {0, 10, 30}, {40, 60, 80}},
        {{20, 30, 90}, {30, 40, 100}, {80, 70, 90}},
        {{20, 20, 40}, {30, 10, 30}, {50, 40, 10}}
    };
    for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h) {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w) {
            printf("%3d %3d %3d | ", image[h][w].rgbtBlue, image[h][w].rgbtGreen, image[h][w].rgbtRed);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will compile, but with warnings:

> warning : variable length array folded to constant array as an
> extension [-Wgnu-folding-constant]

Comment: Sizes could be declared as `enum { width=3, height=3 };` to avoid compiler extensions.

Comment: @user694733 Of course. But Eric had already posted that by the time I had posted my answer, so adding that option would have been 'stealing' his (excellent) answer. So I didn't do it.