# Array to int and Sum of them in C

Tags: arrays, c, integer

im learning C and i am a bit confused with array handling.

I have a task that asks me to sum up 2 arrays of non negative integers.

example array 1 = {1,2,3} , array 2 = {4,5,6} -> 123+456 = 579

I searched a bit for a solution on how to convert those arrays of integers to an integer, but didnt really get helpful information.

I ended up with a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int sum(int A[],int B[], int n){
    int i,j,t,k;
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        t= t+A[i];
    }
    
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        k= k+B[j];
    }
    
    return t+k;
    
}


int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int a[n] = {1,2,3};
    int b[n] = {4,5,6};
    
    printf("%d",sum(a,b,n));

    
    return 0;
}
```

But my result is 1225283 which of course is wrong.
I found a solution where people write something like "t= 10* t+A[i]" , i dont get where that "10* " comes from, but i tested it and then "t" gets "123" but if i try the same for "k" it doesnt work, returning "k" doesnt give me "456". I am a bit confused, whats the proper way of handling this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `t` Hi I'm an uninitialized variable. Set me to zero please. Like the friendly compiler said in the warning it gave. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: You don't need to use a seperate variable in the `for` loop. You can reuse `i`. same for `k`. And as @Lundin said, initialize `t`.

Comment: i didnt get any errors - Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0 , using DevC++

Comment: Ok so in all fairness, gcc is crap for this purpose. You should compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`. Might want to get rid of DevC++ since it isn't maintained since forever. Codeblocks is nice and free and uses a much newer version of gcc by default.

Comment: Interesting, gcc does not even compile the code with the error message: `error: variable-sized object may not be initialized` and it is right about it.

Comment: But `int a[n] = {1,2,3};` will not compile in any compiler unless this is some weird gcc extension I haven't heard of.

Comment: thanks that helped, but what about the "10*" ? what does it do, why do i need it? does it work without it?

Comment: For the GCC error: [“Variable-sized object may not be initialized”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3082914)

Comment: Multiply by 10 is for creating a number like `123` rather than 1+2+3=6. Any number can be formed by val * base^n + val * base^n-1 ...  In case of decimal numbers (base 10), that means 1*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0 = 123. This applies to binary base 2, hex base 16 etc as well.

Comment: as i said i got no errors, no warnings nothing, and why should it not compile? whats the better way to define the array of integers ? what instead of int a[n] = {1,2,3}; ?

Comment: Why not just initialize your arrays as `int a[] = {1,2,3};` and eliminate the VLA concern?

Comment: What is the expected result? `123+456` = `579` or `1+2+3+4+5+6` = `21`?

Comment: im thankful for all this help, but people please read the question carefully......

Comment: The reason it should not compile is that it's not valid C. Or to be more correct, the C standard does not require this to compile, so if this compiles, it's because of compiler extensions. And neither gcc nor clang supports it.

Comment: However, it IS valid C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in sum function, you haven't initialized neighter t nor k but you keep summing them and use later, so every time your code is executed, you chould get different result.

On the other hand, in *something like "t= 10* t+A[i]"*, *10 comes from basic math, where a number could be resolved as a*10^0 + b*10^1 +c*10^2 + .... + m * 10^n. As a result, starting from least significant digit, everytime you try to add new digit (from least to most significant), you need your multipliciant to be 10 times greater.

```
int sum(int A[],int B[], int n){
    int i,j,t=0,k=0,ten=1;
    
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        t += ten*A[i];
        ten *= 10;
    }

    ten = 1; /* initialize again*/
    
    for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--){
        k += ten*B[j];
        ten *= 10;
    }
    
    return t+k;
    
}
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: With that code i get "246" as output, which is wrong.

Comment: yeah maybe both of us should read code first before copy pasting. I did the same operation on array A twice, instead of doing for both A and B. Could you try again?

Comment: *"so every time your code is executed, you should get different result."* - Not necessarily. It's possible, but not required at all.

Comment: yeap, you right. i was aiming to write *could*, my bad

Answer (score 2):

You're basically adding digits 1+2+3 instead of creating the number 123. Your code also has various other flaws, like uninitialized variables. Here is a working example:

```
int array2int(int A[], int n) {
    int ret = 0;

    for(int i=0, k=1; i<n; i++){
        ret = ret + k * A[i];
        k *= 10;
    }

    return ret;
}    

int sum(int A[],int B[], int n){
    return array2int(A, n) + array2int(B, n);    
}
```