# Why we cannot create an array with a constant in c

Tags: c++, c

Why the below piece is a valid C++ code but an - invalid C code?

```
int main(){
    unsigned int const size_of_list = 20;
    const char* list_of_words[size_of_list] = {"Some", "Array"};

    for (unsigned int writing_index = 0; writing_index < size_of_list; writing_index ++)
        ;
        return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `const unsigned int size_of_list = 20;`

Comment: So your question is why does the `c` compiler reject this code but the `c++` compiler accept?

Comment: @Irelia The order of qualifiers doesn't matter.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're allowed to declare variable-length arrays, but you can't use an initializer with them.

Comment: @Barmar Ah okay. I assumed the const was getting ignored

Comment: This question may need more focus if you are really asking the two questions "Why is this valid C++?" and "Why is this invalid C?"  Otherwise there could be a near-infinite number of questions like this.

Comment: @DrewDormann The title seems to indicate that the emphasis is on C.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I reopened it, but there's almost certainly a duplicate for that question as well.

Comment: Just for general interest:  gcc will compile the posted code, albeit with a warning of "variable length array folded to constant array as an extension [-Wgnu-folding-content]" if you specify -pedantic on the compile line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C:
`20` is a constant.
`unsigned int const size_of_list` is **not** a constant.

Title: "Why we cannot create an array with a constant in c" does not apply to this code.

```
const char* list_of_words[size_of_list] = {"Some", "Array"}; // Bad
```

An issue here (and the error message) is why a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) cannot be initialized.  That is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3082914/2410359).

With a constant, array initialization works fine.

```
const char* list_of_words[20] = {"Some", "Array"};  // Good
```

Another issue is mistaking that `const` makes an object a *constant*.  It does not.

---

Alternative C code

```
int main(){
    // unsigned int const size_of_list = 20;
    #define size_of_list 20u

    const char* list_of_words[size_of_list] = {"Some", "Array"};
    for (unsigned int writing_index = 0; writing_index < size_of_list; writing_index ++)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

If you can specify the size in the array itself, then you can get it's size with the `sizeof` operator. This may be better suited for having the compiler count up the size instead manual counting. When not using `C99` VLAs, `sizeof` also yields a compile-time constant.

```
#include <stddef.h> /* size_t */
int main(void) {
    const char* list_of_words[] = {"Some", "Array"};
    const char list_of_char[sizeof list_of_words
        / sizeof *list_of_words] = {'S','A'};
    const size_t size_of_list
        = sizeof list_of_words / sizeof *list_of_words;
    for (size_t writing_index = 0;
        writing_index < size_of_list; writing_index ++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @chux. What is the significance of const then? Could please help me by pointing to some good resources on this?

Comment: `const` directs code to not subsequently change `size_of_list`.  Aside from the C spec, no suggested resources.