# Is it possible to initialize a 2D array by calling two functions? example: array[starting_rows()][starting_columns()]

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array

I'm in the process of programming the game 4-in-a-row in C language, the user is supposed to enter the size of the board, the maximum 2D array (board) that I'm allowed to accept is 25X25.

In short, can I initialize the size of a 2D array by calling for two functions in which the user enters the size of the board. I'm receiving the error

> `Variable-sized object may not be initialized`

on the line

```
int arr[starting_rows()][starting_columns()] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C compile error: "Variable-sized object may not be initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082914/c-compile-error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized)

Comment: Your problem is not related to calling functions. You can only initialize arrays if the size is known as compile time. If you use a value that is only known at runtime (either a variable or return value of a funciton) you are using a variable sized array which cannot be initialized in that way. You need to use loops for set the content.

Comment: @Gerhardh Under C23, umm 24, VLAs can be initialized using an empty initializer: `... = {};`

Comment: The correct solution here is to probably to always declare it as `static int arr[25][25]` and then use as much of that array as required.

Comment: You can also use `memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr)` to initialise to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In short, can I initialize the size of a 2D array by calling for two functions in which the user enters the size of the board (?)

No.
Perhaps in the next version of C ([C24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)))?

`int arr[starting_rows()][starting_columns()]` is a [variable length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).  C presently does not allow initialization of VLAs.

Zero fill it with `memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr)`. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77746469/is-it-possible-to-initialize-a-2d-array-by-calling-two-functions-example-array/77748582#comment137065436_77746469)

Alternatively, define and initialize a maximal sized array: `int arr[25][25] = { 0 }` and use a subset of it. [@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77746469/is-it-possible-to-initialize-a-2d-array-by-calling-two-functions-example-array/77748582#comment137064067_77746469)

---

For OP, I suggest the 2nd approach.  Get user input and handle potential out-of-range values, incomplete input, input errors, etc. and *then*, if all is good, proceed to array declaration.